# How to position a view on top of another view in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

I have a `TextView` (indicated in green below) and a `LinearLayout` (indicated in red below) in a `RelativeLayout`. I want to position the TextView on top of the `LinearLayout`, like this:
[image]

However, I tried this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout">
    <!--some other views-->
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" <!--this because the textview is the topmost view on the screen so I tried to use this-->
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/linear_layout"
    android:text="my text"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>
```

However, when I run the app, it is like this:

[image]

So I want to know what did I do wrong and how to fix it. Is there an xml attribute that I can use?

If you need more code to identify the problem, feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your `LinearLayout` after `TextView` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" <!-- this because the textview is the topmost view on the screen so I tried to use this -->
    android:text="my text"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:id="@+id/text1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout">
    <!-- some other views -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you can do it by
`text1.bringToFront();`

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:layout_below:"@+id/text1">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your layout with following one should work.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/linear_layout"
    android:text="my text"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout">
    <!--some other views-->
</LinearLayout>
```